# How do I modify the width of a TabContainer in Dojo

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I'm experimenting with Dojo, so far it's very cool except for the fact that I can't seem to be able set the width of a TabContainer. I have the following code

```
<div id="tabs" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" doLayout="false">
    <div id="javaTab" class="myTab" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Java">
        <h1>Hello I'm the Java Tab</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="rubyTab" class="myTab" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Ruby">
        <h1>Hello I'm the Ruby Tab</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This are the CSS:

```
#tabs {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.myTab {
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

If I put a menu bar inside the the tabs then I find that their width is larger than my screen so I don't see the complete bar.
So is there a way to set the width of the generated "tab bar"?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Based on your description, it seems that you want to change the size of menu bar inside of a tab, not change the size of a TabContainer. Can you clarify it?

Comment: well, my menu bar has 100% of it's father, this being a div that dojo creates with a huge width (larger than the width of body in my case). So the thing I want to do is change this width to match the width of its parent container

Comment: don't set the width/height on the individual tabs.  Their size is determined by the TabContainer

Answer (score 0):

Yup Peller is right, you can't set the size on each contentPane, but what you can do is to modify the width of the whole thing (tabContainer)